# Two sample dependent T test in python and rank sum test

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy, t-test

I have a data set for which has two labels, label 1 = 0(case), label 2 =1(control). I have already calculated the mean for the two different labels. Furthermore, I need to calculate two sample t test(dependent) and two sample rank sum test. My data set looks like :

```
SRA ID  ERR169499           ERR169500           ERR169501           mean_ctrl   mean_case
Label   1                   0                   1
TaxID   PRJEB3251_ERR169499 PRJEB3251_ERR169500 PRJEB3251_ERR169501
333046  0.05                0                   0.4
1049    0.03                0.9                 0
337090  0.01                0.6                 0.7
```

I am new to statistics.The code I have so far is this:

```
label = []
data = {}

x = open('final_out_transposed.csv','rt')
for r in x:
datas = r.split(',')
if datas[0] == ' Label':
    label.append(r.split(",")[1:])
label = label[0]
label[-1] = label[-1].replace('\n','')
counter = len(label)

for row in file1:
content = row.split(',')
if content[0]=='SRA ID' or content[0]== 'TaxID' or content[0]==' Label':
    pass
else:
    dt = row.split(',')
    dt[-1] = dt[-1].replace('\n','')
    data[dt[0]]=dt[1:]
keys = list(data)

sum_file = open('sum.csv','w')
for key in keys:
sum_case = 0
sum_ctrl = 0
count_case = 0
count_ctrl = 0
mean_case = 0
mean_ctrl = 0
print(len(label))
for i in range(counter):
    print(i)
    if label[i] == '0' or label[i] == 0:
        sum_case=np.float64(sum_case)+np.float64(data[key][i])
        count_case = count_case+1
        mean_case = sum_case/count_case
    else:
        sum_ctrl = np.float64(sum_ctrl)+np.float64(data[key][i])
        count_ctrl = count_ctrl+1
        mean_ctrl = sum_ctrl/count_ctrl
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using open to read your csv file, I would use Pandas. That will place it in a dataframe that will be easier to use

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_csv('final_out_transposed.csv')
```

For a Two Sample dependent T-test you want to use [ttest_rel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html)

**notice** ttest_ind is for *independent groups*. Since you specifically asked for *dependent groups*, use ttest_rel.

It's hard from your example above to see where your two columns of sample data are, but imagine I had the following made up data of 'case' and 'control'. I could calculate a dependent Two Sample t-test using pandas as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_rel
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({
'case':[55, 43, 51, 62, 35, 48, 58, 45, 48, 54, 56, 32],
'control':[48, 38, 53, 58, 36, 42, 55, 40, 49, 50, 58, 25]})
(t_stat, p) = ttest_rel(data_frame['control'], data_frame['case'])
print (t_stat)
print (p)
```

p would be the p-value, t_stat would be the t-statistic. You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html)

In a similar manner, once you have your sample .csv data in a dataframe, you can perform a rank sum test:

```
from scipy.stats import ranksums
(t_stat, p) = ranksums(data_frame['control'], data_frame['case'])
```

[documentation for ranksums](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ranksums.html)

Comment: My samples are categorized as label 0 and 1. Like in the example I have shown only three columns, similarly there are 187 columns which are divided as case(0) and contro(1)l. I have already calculated sum and mean for case and control can I use any of those columns as my two samples using "use_cols" in dataframe ? If not any one from mean and sum  how can i proceed with 187 columns

Comment: Hi, I tried doing what you suggested with my data. I am getting the keyerror: control. I tried doing it "(t_stat, p) = ttest_rel(data_frame1['case'], data_frame2['control'])" with this I am getting follwing errors : RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice **kwargs) , RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b), RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b), RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)

Comment: From the error, it looks like there is a NaN value in one of your dataframes. You might try `data_frame1.isnull().values.any()` and `data_frame2.isnull().values.any()`. You can use `data_frame.dropna(inplace=True)` to remove null values.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested, after this i am getting the error : IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: for rank sum im getting the same value for all the rows, do I need to iterate?

Comment: Something doesn't sound right. If you print type `print(data_frame1['case'].dtypes)` do you see `float64'? Also, try `type(data_frame1['case'])` and make sure it's a pandas.core.series.Series. It sounds like something is not shaped correctly in the data_frames.

Comment: Yes, Im getting float64 after print(data_frame1['case'].dtypes) and with type(data_frame1['case']) Im getting the error : TypeError: __array__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Im still getting the error IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Comment: If I do: ttest_rel(a, b) and the obtained t value is negative, does this mean that the mean of b is greater than the mean of a ?